# dplyr: difference between values measured at same location, different date

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with the data set below.

```
Date    Depth   Magnitude
9/11/14 0.1     19.64
9/11/14 1       19.64
9/11/14 2       19.63
9/11/14 4       19.57
9/11/14 5.5     19.3
9/11/14 7       16.5
9/11/14 9       11.31
9/11/14 11      10.11
9/11/14 13      9.31
9/11/14 15      9.03
9/11/14 16.9    9.03
9/16/14 0.1     19.87
9/16/14 1       19.17
9/16/14 2       18.91
9/16/14 4       18.18
9/16/14 5.5     17.53
9/16/14 7       14.29
9/16/14 9       10.81
9/16/14 11      9.88
9/16/14 13      9.22
9/16/14 15      9.11
9/16/14 16.9    8.98
```

As you can see, there are values at given depths on two different dates. What I'd like to do using dplyr is calculate the change in "magnitude" between the two dates at each depth. For example, at depth 0.1, magnitude changes by 19.87 - 19.64 = 0.23. I'd like to do this for all depths.

I can do this using intermediate variables, but it is super clunky:

```
FirstDate <- MyData %>% filter(Date == "9/11/14")
SecondDate <- MyData %>% filter(Date == "9/16/14")
SecondDate$Magnitude - FirstDate$Magnitude
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant dplyr-esque way of achieving this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm.. just `MyData %>% group_by(Depth) %>% summarise(diff(Magnitude))`?

Comment: In case you have more dates you want to find differences between, try `reshape2::dcast(MyData, Depth ~ Date)`, then you can play with the columns as you usually might

Comment: Thanks for the replies. That's exactly what I was looking for, @DavidArenburg. (I don't see the tick sign next to your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer, though...)

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run `diff(Magnitude)` per `Depth`

```
MyData %>% 
 group_by(Depth) %>% 
 summarise(diff(Magnitude))

#    Depth diff(Magnitude, 1)
#    (dbl)              (dbl)
# 1    0.1               0.23
# 2    1.0              -0.47
# 3    2.0              -0.72
# 4    4.0              -1.39
# 5    5.5              -1.77
# 6    7.0              -2.21
# 7    9.0              -0.50
# 8   11.0              -0.23
# 9   13.0              -0.09
# 10  15.0               0.08
# 11  16.9              -0.05
```

Comment: Also `setDT(MyData)[, list(Magnitude= diff(Magnitude)), by = Depth]`